# Need to restart python in Terminal every time a change is made to script

Tags: python

Every time I make a change to a python script I have to reload python and re-import the module. Please advise how I can modify my scripts and run then without having to relaunch python in the terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! At least python has a reload. PHP just freaks out and dies with a 'cannot redeclare function' blah blah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a suggestion, based on your comment describing your work flow:

> first, i run python3.1 in terminal second, i do "import module" then, i run a method from the module lets say "module.method(arg)" every time, i try to debug the code, i have to do this entire sequence, even though the change is minor. it is highly inefficient

Instead of firing up the interactive Python shell, make the module itself executable.  The easiest way to do this is to add a block to the bottom of the module like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    method(arg) # matches what you run manually in the Python shell
```

Then, instead of running python3.1, then importing the module, then calling the method, you can do something like this:

```
python3.1 modulename.py
```

and Python will run whatever code is in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.  But that code will not be run if the module is imported by another Python module.  More information on this common Python idiom can be found [in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts).

The advantage of this is that when you make a change to your code, you can usually just re-run the module by pressing the up arrow and hitting enter.  No messy reloading necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just some module that's changing, you can call [reload(module)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) in your script.

Comment: This is correct, but note that if you follow the link you'll see there are several caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you enter script directly into the interactive python shall, or are you executing your .py file from the terminal by running something like `python myscript.py`?

Comment: first, i run python3.1 in terminal
second, i do "import module"
then, i run a method from the module lets say "module.method(arg)"

every time, i try to debug the code, i have to do this entire sequence, even though the change is minor. it is highly inefficient

Comment: *Update:* I see Will McCutchen beat me to the punch.
What you will what to do is to write you script in a file instead of doing it in the terminal. Say, for example your file is named "myscript.py". Write all the commands in that then just `python3.1 myscript.py` in the same folder as your script is placed and it will be run. That way you don't have to type in the commands every time. What OS are you running, windows?

Answer (score 1):

I found a bypass online. Magic commands exist. It works like a charm for me. The Reload option didn't work for me. Got it from [here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart?page=1#comment_203342093)  and point 3 of this link.

Basically all you have to do is the following: and changes you make are reflected automatically after you save.

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2

In [3]: Import MODULE

In [4]: my_class = Module.class()
        my_class.printham()
Out[4]: ham

In [5]: #make changes to printham and save
In [6]: my_class.printham() 
Out[6]: hamlet
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) to re-import a module. I use it frequently when using the interactive mode to debug code.

However, from a higher level, I would be hesitant to use that in a production version of a program. Unless you will have very strict control over how sub-modules are changing, it would not be hard to have the reloaded module change in some way that breaks your program. Unless your program really needs 100% up-time, it would make sense to stop it and start it again when there is some kind of version change.

Comment: For Python 3, reload was moved to `imp`, so you'll have to `import imp` and then `imp.reload(mod)`