# Is it possible to `refresh` cmd, so that it now runs the `updated` python file?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, cmd, read-eval-print-loop

For example, if I have a file called `test.py` which looks like the following:

```
a = 3
```

and I run from cmd:

`python -i test.py`, and then just type `a`, I get returned `3`. Let's say in the actual `test.py` I change the value of `a` to `4`.

Now we have

```
a = 4
```

I save, when I go back to the `cmd` (I never closed it), and type `a`, its still `3`. I have to restart the terminal, do the `python -i test.py` again to get the updated version. This is why I want to know if there's a way to `reload`, or `update` cmd of the current changes.

Comment: take a look at this feature of ipython: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehR82oydw-c

Comment: possible dupe or possibly related to: [Need to restart python in Terminal every time a change is made to script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374542/need-to-restart-python-in-terminal-every-time-a-change-is-made-to-script)

Comment: Unforuntately thats not it completly, cause I may have many functions